# How to extract all objects from all ids have linked with foreign key in django?

Tags: django, sqlite

using Django 1.9
How to extract all objects from class table that linked with another class table by foreign key.
**I mean not all objects from one id but i mean all objects from all ids** in one page. when i'm trying it gives me just one result

For instance:
urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    # /music/
    url(r"^$", views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    # /music/123/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='details'),
    # /music/song/
    url(r'^song/$', views.songView, name='songs'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Album, Song
from django.shortcuts import render


class HomeView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/details.html'


# Get all songs from all album (extracting songs from all of the albums in one page)
def songView(request):
    for albums in Album.objects.all():
        all_album = Album.objects.get(id=albums.id)
        all_song = all_album.song_set.all()
    return render(request, 'music/song.html', {'all_song': all_song})
```

songs.html

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block body %}

    {% for song in all_song %}
        <h2>{{ song }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another simple way to get the values in template is:

```
def songView(request):
    album = Album.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'music/song.html', {'album': album})
```

and in your templates you can iterate this way

```
{% for item in album %}
    <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
{% for song in item.song_set.all %}
    <h2>{{ song.title }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just iterating through the Album objects and on every interaction rewrite the `all_song` variable without storing it somewhere. The proper way would be:

```
def songView(request):
    songs = []
    for album in Album.objects.all():
        songs_per_album = album.song_set.all()
        songs.append(song_per_album)
    return render(request, 'music/song.html', {'all_song': songs})
```

Also, take a look at serializers it can be useful when serializing nested structures.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you doing this?

```
def songView(request):
    for albums in Album.objects.all():
        all_album = Album.objects.get(id=albums.id)
        all_song = all_album.song_set.all()
    return render(request, 'music/song.html', {'all_song': all_song})
```

You get all albums and than again make request to db to get album, and you just get all songs of specific album, if you want to get all songs just get all of them

```
songs = Song.objects.all()
```

if you want to get songs where album fk not null you can do like this:

```
album_ids = list(Album.objest.values_list('id', flat=True))
songs = Song.objects.filter(album_id__in=album_ids)
or 
songs = Song.objects.filter(album_isnull=False)
```

Comment: i thought i can't handle Song.objects.all unless if it away from foreign key only
thank u Bakhtiyar Bekbergen it's become easy now.
but could you tell me values_list what does it is?

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin read more about Django ORM, it will be helpful, I am using in code above values_list to get list of id of needed objects in this case it's Album